# Could someone confirm that the database.sql on a 'platform' [site specific folder] in Aegir is readable in MySQL and WAMP in particular?

Tags: drupal

This is a noobe question.  I am trying to clone a Drupal website on WAMP to test some local development. The current website is maintained on Aegir. With the owners' knowledge but for reasons that I don't know, I have not been able to get information directly from whomever is managing the website.

I have been able to scp the platform [profiles, modules, files etc].  My current puzzle is how to obtain a copy of the database so that I can import it into WAMP.

One of the files that I have copied is called database.sql and is a healthy size (35MB). I have looked around the web and no one outright says this is a readable form of the MySQL database.

My attempts to import it into a database of the same name and username failed with a suggestion the size was too large. (password unknown - have several versions looking at the documentation and cannot tell which one is which).

Working from the MySQL console: mysql -u usernamenewdatabase -p newdatabasename < C:/path/database.sql
Also failed.

Can anyone cut through this muddle for me?  Am I even on the right track?

Thanks
Jo

Comment: What's the **exact** error you get when importing the data? Something about max packet size by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for jogging me along.  WAMP just replies with a suggestion that the file is too big.

I have solved it in the meantime.

Yes - database.sql in Aegir is a straightforward .sql file

To get it into WAMP in particular, the solution is to edit this line of config.inc.php file in the wamp/apps/phpAdmin folder

$cfg['UploadDir'] = 'upload';

by inserting upload beween the ''

And then add a subdirectory to phpAdmin called upload.

Put the big file in the upload directory and import it into a clean database from the phpAdmin screen.

Ridiculously easy when we know how.

Thanks Clive -  I appreciate the support.